# Counting grep results

Tags: bash, sh

I'm new to bash so I'm finding trouble doing something very basic.
 Through playing with various scripts I found out that the following script prints the lines that contain the "word"

```
for file in*; do
    cat $file | grep "word"
done
```

doing the following:

```
for file in*; do
    cat $file | grep "word" | wc -l
done
```

had a result of printing in every iteration how many times did the "word" appeared on file.

- How can I implement a counter for all those appearances and in the
  end just `echo` the counter?

I used a counter that way but it appeared 0.

```
 let x+=cat $filename | grep "word"
```

Comment: You can pipe the output from your loop `for file in *; do cat $file | grep "word"; done | wc -l`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pipe the entire loop to `wc -l`.

```
for file in *; do
    cat $file | grep "word"
done | wc -l
```

This is a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). How about:

```
for file in *; do
    grep "word" "$file"
done | wc -l
```

Actually, the entire loop is unnecessary if you pass all the file names to `grep` at once.

```
grep "word" * | wc -l
```

Note that if `word` shows up more than once on the same line these solutions will only count the entire line once. If you want to count same-line occurrences separately you can use `-o` to print each match on a separate line:

```
grep -o "word" * | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

The oneliner in John's answer is the way to go. Just to satisfy your curiosity:

```
sum=0
for f in *; do
    x="$(grep 'word' "$f" | wc -l)"
    echo "x: $x"
    (( sum += x ))
done
echo "sum: $sum"
```

If the line containing the `grep` and `wc` does not yield a number you are SOL. That is why you should stick to the other solution or do a pure bash implementation with things like `read`, '`case` and `*word*)`' or `if [[ "$line" =~ "$re_containing_word" ]]; then ...`